# padding missing rows between two data frames in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two large data frames A (N1 by 6), B (N2 by 2). The first two columns of A are the keys for matching B, all keys in A is a subset of B.

What I want to do is: padding A with those keys that are in B but not in A, and fill other 4 columns with "NA", reserve for missing value imputation later.

```
A  
1 2 3 4 5 6    
1 3 4 5 6 7

B  
1 2  
1 3  
1 4

My new A  
1 2 3 4 5 6    
1 3 4 5 6 7  
1 4 NA NA NA NA
```

I come up with something like this

```
rowDiff <- setdiff(A[,1:2],B)  
pad <- cbind(rowDiff, matrix(rep("NA",4*nrow(rowDiff)),ncol=4))  
A <- rowbind(A,pad)
```

Any more efficient solution?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
 merge(B, A, all.x=TRUE)
```

It tests OK:

```
> A  <- read.table(text="1 2 3 4 5 6    
+ 1 3 4 5 6 7")
> 
> B  <- read.table(text="1 2  
+ 1 3  
+ 1 4")
> merge(B, A, all.x=TRUE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  3  4  5  6  7
3  1  4 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Rstudio throws out an out of memory message for my original large data set. Any alternative?

Comment: Use `library(dplyr); left_join(B,A)`